# Android car navigation that gives shortest drivable route, disregarding time and fuel efficiency

Tags: android, navigation

I’m in a situation where even with forbidding motorway I’m ending up with a 110 Km deviation to the north or the south for driving straight to the east.
I want the shortest path in Km even if takes way longer and burn more fuel (fuel economic routes also have such high deviation).

The best way to achieve this is to configure for pedestrian mode *(I checked in that case the route is almost a straight line instead of a curve with car mode whatever the guiding software)*. The problem is I’m not find taking stairs with the car.

So how to get the shortest path which excludes roads where cars can’t go through ?